# Best practices for storing user API keys in localStorage

Tags: javascript, security, local-storage, single-page-application

I am producing SPA that trades in cryptocurrency through API.

Since entering an API key every time is not user-friendly, I would like to save it in LocalStorage.
(I don't want to keep it on the server.)

I intend to store non encrypt json in the following format:

```
{
  "exchange1" : { key: "api key", secret : "secret key"},
  "exchange2" : { key: "api key", secret : "secret key"},
  and more...
}
```

Prompts the user to avoid using it on shared machines before saving.
Are there security risks?

Or is it better to produce with Electron and Cordova instead of a website?

Comment: SO expects questions which can be answered not discussed,

Comment: Something to at least be considered for security sensitive applications; https://www.rdegges.com/2018/please-stop-using-local-storage/#why-local-storage-is-insecure-and-you-shouldn-t-use-it-to-store-sensitive-data

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thank you. I learned a lot.
I will no longer develop this app because I do not have much time to think about server-side security.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC that's the main problem with this site.